# WSO2 Identity Server Limit on the number of IDP's

Tags: wso2

I have being evaluating WSO2 Identity Server for an upcoming project. However we have a use case that would require 3,000+ SAML IDP's to be added for a given service. I can't find the relevant info online for the following.

Is there a limit on the number of IDP's you can add to WSO2?
What performance impact would it have? 
If you have worked with the product at a very large scale, can you share your experience?
We are looking at 20 million+

Many thanks! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no exact limitation for number of IDPs. This depends on the system resources. 
There might be a performance impact based on number of concurrent users, network latency, system resources etc.